# Generating vector tiles with Mapnik

Tags: mapnik, vector-tiles

Is it possible to generate Vector Tiles using the 2.2.0 Mapnik release? If so, please give a sample configuration or point to an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Mapnik 2.2.0 will not generate vector tiles out of the box. To enable this functionality, it must be compiled with C++ headers available [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile).

Answer (score 3):

You could find a good point to start [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile).

Answer (score 2):

It's the other way around. Mapnik is software to render images from data. Vector tiles are data. You can use Mapnik to render images from Vector Tiles. You cannot use Mapnik to output Vector Tiles.

Comment: Vector tiles are data, but "rendered" nevertheless. Mapnik does support rendering data into vector tiles, but there doesn't seem to be any built-in flag to do this out of the box. The link posted by MickyInTheSky has C++ headers that may add this functionality to Mapnik 2.2.0 and 3.0.x.