# How to compile Mapnik 2.2.0 with mapnik-vector-tile headers

Tags: mapnik, vector-tiles

I want to generate vector tiles with Mapnik 2.2.0 (That's the latest version that can be installed on debian wheezy). According to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144095/59683) answer, I need to compile mapnik with [mapnik-vector-tile](https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile) which provides C++ headers. `v0.6.x` of mapnik-vector-tile supports Mapnik 2.2.0 so I can use that.

How do I compile mapnik with those headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An simple example project using mapnik and mapnik-vector-tile for generating vector tiles is at:

https://github.com/vross/vector-tiles-producer

The repo contains Makefile demonstrating the compilation with C++.